# Using custom decorators to wrap form elements inside div's with zend_form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm looking for a way to wrap zend_form form elements inside div's.
I can get the desired result by using the code below inside the form class.

```
                $element->setDecorators(array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Description',
                'Errors',
                array(array('top-left' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-top-left')),
                array(array('top-right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-top-right')),
                array(array('top-center' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-top-center')),
                array(array('bottom-left' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-bottom-left')),
                array(array('bottom-right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-bottom-right')),
                array(array('bottom-center' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-bottom-center')),
                array(array('left' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-left')),
                array(array('right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-right')),
                array(array('dd' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'id' => $element->getLabel().'-element')),
                array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
            ));
```

I would like to know if I could use custom decorators to achieve the desired result.

The code above is very easy to implement but has to be done for every element.
So then I thought, could I use a custom decorator to achieve the same result?

So far I've not been able to, which is why I'm asking this question here.

::Edit::

I forgot to mention what I've been trying to do so far.
I have been trying to break down the form inside my custom decorator. 
But I've had no luck so far.

```
class Form_Decorator_Borders extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
```

{

```
public function render($content)
{
    $element    = $this->getElement();          // get form
    $elements   = $element->getElements();      // get form elements
    $placement  = $this->getPlacement();
    $name       = htmlentities($element->getFullyQualifiedName());
    $id         = htmlentities($element->getId());

    foreach ($elements as $k => $v) {
        if (is_object($v) && get_class($v) == "Zend_Form_Element_Text") {
            $elements[$k]->setDecorators(array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Description',
                'Errors',
                array(array('top-left' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-top-left')),
                array(array('top-right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-top-right')),
                array(array('top-center' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-top-center')),
                array(array('bottom-left' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-bottom-left')),
                array(array('bottom-right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-corner-bottom-right')),
                array(array('bottom-center' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-bottom-center')),
                array(array('left' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-left')),
                array(array('right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-right')),
                array(array('dd' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'id' => $elements[$k]->getLabel().'-element')),
                array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
            ));
        }
    }

    $element->setElements($elements);
    $this->setElement($element);

    $this->setElement($element);
    return $this->getElement()->getView()->render($name);
}
```

}

Comment: What's this supposed to look like in html?

Comment: I've uploaded a sample to imageshack: http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/6411/sampledl.png

Comment: The code is supposed to create the borders around the input elements so I have rounded corners without the hassle of CSS3 (for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to use a different approach.
This is what I'm currently using and is working fine so far.

```
public function render($content)
{
    $innerHTML = "";
    //Create a new DOM document
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    //Parse the HTML. The @ is used to suppress any parsing errors
    //that will be thrown if the $html string isn't valid XHTML.
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    //Get all inputs. You could also use any other tag name here,
    //like 'img' or 'table', to extract other tags.
    $eInputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');

    //Iterate over the extracted dds
    foreach ($eInputs as $eInput) {
        if ($eInput->getAttribute('type') == "text") {
            $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($eInput,true));
            $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML()."&nbsp;";
        } else if ($eInput->getAttribute('type') == "password") {
            $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
            $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($eInput,true));
            $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML()."&nbsp;";
        }
    }

    $inputs = explode("&nbsp;", $innerHTML);

    foreach ($inputs as $input) {
        if (!empty($input)) {
            $input = str_replace(">", " />", $input);
            $input = substr($input, 0, -1);
            $replace = '<div class="content-border-bottom-center">
                <div class="content-border-top-center">
                    <div class="content-border-corner-bottom-right">
                        <div class="content-border-corner-bottom-left">
                            <div class="content-border-corner-top-right">
                                <div class="content-border-corner-top-left">
                                    '.$input.'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
            $content = str_replace($input, $replace, $content);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More easy to create extended Zend_Form class with private property for your borders.

```
class Custom_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    /**
     * array
     */
    private $_borderDecorators = array(/*...*/);
}
```

And for Custom_Form's element do next thing (works if decorators set in the class extended from Custom_Form):

```
$element->setDecorators($this->_borderDecorators);
```

Comment: This is a really good tip and I thank you for it. Didn't think of it before (stupid me).
Though this does not give me the desired result.
http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/6411/sampledl.png is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you show your code? It should works fine if you do all right.

Comment: private $_borderDecorators = array(array(array('top-left' => 'HtmlTag'),array(array('bottom-center' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-left')),array(array('right' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'content-border-right')));

and for the element: $keywords->addDecorators($this->_borderDecorators);

had to cut down the amount of the array's so might be a mistake there but just ignore it.

Still I have trouble seeing the right way of wrapping the div's only around the input element. They currently wrap around the dt and dd tag which it's not supposed to.